# GNUPG how to encrypt file without it's original extension in the name?

Tags: gnupg

I need to automatically encrypt file e.g. myfile.xls to myfile.gpg.
Now when I'm trying to encrypt it automatically or with GNU privacy assistent, the encrypted file is myfile.xls.gpg. When I delete that .xls, it has no extension after decrypting.
Thank you.

Comment: why do you need to remove the "extra" extension? It is logical that after you remove it, you can't automagically add it back when you decrypt your file, unless you bind the specific extension to the specific file name (myfile will be always a .xls) or invent a naming schema (e.g. all files beginning with "m" are .xls); maybe using "file" or similar utilities can fix it too... but I think it is not a good idea!

Comment: Hi Shin. Thank you. I think the same that it's stupid decision to rename it, but managers in our bank want it that way. The naming schema you mentioned is not possible, because file names are exacly specified. I wonder if it's possible to make it as I wrote. For example, when you zip files, they have extension .zip and after decompression it has original extension. I know this is little bit different, but...is it possible or not? Thanks!

Comment: Zip is an arhiver and it stores the filenames of course. The only chance you have is if gpg adds such an information in the final encrypted file; the ascii armor of gpg-ed file contains extra info like the version of the gpg used; so that maybe also other info could be added

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If you're asking how to remove the `.xls` extension, a simple shell script can do that. If you're asking how to recover the `.xls` extension when decrypting the file, well, removing the `.xls` loses information. Do you know *why* the managers in your bank want to discard this important piece of information?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That gpgencrypt.c option looks like far too much effort.

To encrypt do this:

```
gpg -er $recipient_id -o myfile.gpg myfile.xls
```

To decrypt and restore the original filename do this:

```
gpg --use-embedded-filename -d myfile.gpg
```

That name has been encrypted and is stored with the encrypted data.  That flag tells GPG to use the original filename instead of creating a new filename based on the name of the encrypted file.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done easily with a simple C app that controls the output. The below file can do what you are looking for, you just need to compile it (linked against libgpgme) and then pass it the input file, the desired output file and the key-ids to use for encryption.

To compile using gcc, simply save the code below as gpgencrypt.c, and compile with `gcc gpgencrypt.c -lgpgme -o gpgencrypt`. (you need libgpgme installed)

The invocation syntax is `gpgencrypt <input file> <output file> <encrypt to>`. i.e. `gpgencrypt myfile.xls myfile.gpg 01234567 12345678`

file: gpgencrypt.c

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <locale.h>

#include <gpgme.h>

#define fail_if_err(err)                                    \
    do {                                                    \
        if (err) {                                          \
            fprintf (stderr, "%s:%d: %s: %s\n",             \
                __FILE__, __LINE__, gpgme_strsource (err),  \
                gpgme_strerror (err));                      \
            exit (1);                                       \
        }                                                   \
    }                                                       \
    while (0)

typedef char * string;

void gpgEncrypt(const char *fileToEncrypt, const char *outputFileName,
                char *encryptTo[],
                int encryptToLength) {
    gpgme_ctx_t ctx;
    gpgme_error_t err;
    gpgme_data_t in, out;
    gpgme_encrypt_result_t enc_result;
    FILE *outputFile;
    gpgme_key_t keys[encryptToLength];
    int nrecipients = 0;
    int BUF_SIZE = 512;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE + 1];
    int ret;

    /* Begin setup of GPGME */
    gpgme_check_version (NULL);
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
    gpgme_set_locale (NULL, LC_CTYPE, setlocale (LC_CTYPE, NULL));
#ifndef HAVE_W32_SYSTEM
    gpgme_set_locale (NULL, LC_MESSAGES, setlocale (LC_MESSAGES, NULL));
#endif
    /* End setup of GPGME */

    // Create the GPGME Context
    err = gpgme_new (&ctx);
    // Error handling
    fail_if_err (err);

    // Set the context to textmode
    gpgme_set_textmode (ctx, 1);
    // Enable ASCII armor on the context
    gpgme_set_armor (ctx, 1);

    // Create a data object pointing to the input file
    err = gpgme_data_new_from_file (&in, fileToEncrypt, 1);
    // Error handling
    fail_if_err (err);

    // Create a data object pointing to the out buffer
    err = gpgme_data_new (&out);
    // Error handling
    fail_if_err (err);

    // Retrieve the keys used to encrypt to
    for (nrecipients=0; nrecipients < encryptToLength; nrecipients++) {
        printf("Retrieving key: %s, %i of %i\n", encryptTo[nrecipients], nrecipients, encryptToLength);
        err = gpgme_get_key (ctx, encryptTo[nrecipients], &keys[nrecipients], 0);

        if(err != GPG_ERR_NO_ERROR)
            printf("error");
    }

    // NULL terminate the key array
    keys[nrecipients] = NULL;

    // Encrypt the contents of "in" using the defined mode and place it into "out"
    err = gpgme_op_encrypt (ctx, keys, GPGME_ENCRYPT_ALWAYS_TRUST, in, out);
    // Error handling
    fail_if_err (err);

    // Retrieve the encrypt result from the context
    enc_result = gpgme_op_encrypt_result (ctx);

    // Check for invalid recipients
    if (enc_result->invalid_recipients) {
        fail_if_err (err);
    }

    // Open the output file
    outputFile = fopen (outputFileName, "w+");

    // Rewind the "out" data object
    ret = gpgme_data_seek (out, 0, SEEK_SET);
    // Error handling
    if (ret)
        fail_if_err (gpgme_err_code_from_errno (errno));

    // Read the contents of "out" and place it into buf
    while ((ret = gpgme_data_read (out, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
        // Write the contents of "buf" to "outputFile"
        fwrite (buf, ret, 1, outputFile);
    }

    // Error handling
    if (ret < 0)
        fail_if_err (gpgme_err_code_from_errno (errno));

    // Close "outputFile"
    fclose(outputFile);

    // Unreference the key objects
    for (nrecipients=0; nrecipients < sizeof(&keys) / sizeof(int) + 1; nrecipients++) {
        if (keys[nrecipients]) {
            printf ("Releasing key: %s\n", keys[nrecipients]->subkeys->fpr);
            gpgme_key_unref (keys[nrecipients]);
        }
    }

    // Release the "in" data object
    gpgme_data_release (in);
    // Release the "out" data object
    gpgme_data_release (out);
    // Release the context
    gpgme_release (ctx);
}

int 
main (int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 4) {
        printf ("Usage: gpgencrypt <input file> <output file> <encrypt to>\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    int pos, n;
    string encryptToList[argc - 4];

    printf ("Encrypting %s and placing the result into %s\n",
                argv[1], argv[2]);

    for (pos=3; pos < argc; pos++) {
        encryptToList[n] = argv[pos];
        n++;
    }
    gpgEncrypt (argv[1], argv[2], encryptToList, argc - 3);
    return 0;
}
```